# Incomplete link for create account request email from bugzilla

Tags: bugzilla

The email i got has incomplete link , i.e. a link without host name & http:// for creating account, how can i set my custom host with http:// for every link sent from bugzillain email ? Please reply fast as i m in the middle of the configuration process.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the `urlbase` parameter.